# How to get the first digits from a column name?

Tags: python, pandas, list

my column names are 22abcd123, 33sdfjsdh77, 45hgvjh77, 44vhsfgdhd88
i need my column name as 22,33,45,44.

I tried:
res = int(re.findall('(\d+)',df.columns[5])[0])
i got the answer for 1 column name . but I need it for every column name in a Dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
```

Comment: The result is: Index(['22', '33', '45', '44'], dtype='object'). I would like to get the result as : [22, 33, 45, 44]

Answer (score 0):

First you can get all of your column names as an array using:

```
myArray = pandas.columns(df)
```

Now you have an array of column names in myArray

Now write a loop to get your new column names and add the new column names to an array:

```
newArray = []
for i in myArray:
     newColName = myArray[i][0:2]
     newArray = newArray.append(newColName)
     i=i+1
```